# Deriving a function with a given Taylor expansion

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

$F(x)=1+\dfrac{x^2}{2!\cdot1!}+\dfrac{x^4}{4!\cdot2!}+\dfrac{x^6}{6!\cdot3!}+\dfrac{x^8}{8!\cdot4!}\cdots$

I wanted to know the function which could be represented as the Taylor series mentioned.

Every $2n$-th derivative gives $\dfrac{1}{n!}$ at $x=0$

It seems analogous to
${\cos(ix)}=1+\dfrac{x^2}{2!}+\dfrac{x^4}{4!}+\dfrac{x^6}{6!}+\dfrac{x^8}{8!}\cdots$

But I don't see how I can transform the expression into a familiar function.

Comment: It is a generalised hypergeometric function: $$
\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{x^{2n} }}{{(2n)!n!}}}  = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{\Gamma (1/2)\Gamma (1)}}{{\Gamma (n + 1/2)\Gamma (n + 1)}}\frac{1}{{n!}}\left( {\frac{{x^2 }}{4}} \right)^n }  = {}_0F_2\! \left( {;\frac{1}{2},1;\frac{{x^2 }}{4}} \right).
$$

Comment: Ohh so there isn't an elementary trigonometric equation for the expression :( Thank you for answering